# Enable Conditional Field using another Template Tag

Tags: docusignapi

Can we enable/disable the Conditional Field based on the another template Data Field as Parent Tag and Parent Value in Current Template?

Consider We have 2 Templates (A & B), Template A having CheckBox Field and  Template B having 2 Data Fields. Now We have created an Envelope X using Template A & B. I would like to enable the 2 Data Fields using Conditional Field Option(Parent Tag and Value) in Template B, when Recipient has selected (checked) CheckBox in Template A. Please let me know How can I achieve this option in DocuSign API?

Comment: Someone may correct me, but I don't think that this is possible. But if it is I want to know, it would be tremendously useful to me.

Comment: Can anyone respond for my question?

Comment: There is no unique syntax to reference a tab from another template - if you are specifying a conditionalParentLabel  value that exists on another template and receive this error: CONDITIONALTAB_HAS_INVALID_PARENT, that would indicate it is not possible (IMO).